# React > Conditional Suspense Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks for taking the time to read this, for a bit of background I'm using React 17 with Webpack.

Within my main component, I have many conditional child components (dependant upon my state) - which for performance reasons I want to Lazy Load (only when and if needed).

However, using my current solution any time my "ParentComponent" is re-rendered (state change), the Child Component is too re-loaded (regardless if "state.somevalue" has been updated or not) and loses its own state and flickers where the HTML is re-rendered.

Here is an example:

```
   class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    
        __renderChildComponent1(){
            const ChildComponent = React.lazy(() => 
                import(
                    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
                    /* webpackChunkName: "childa" */ './ChildA.jsx'
                )
            );
            
            return (
                <Suspense fallback="">
                    <ChildComponent myprop={ this.state.somevalue } />
                </Suspense>
            )
        }
    
        __renderChildComponent2(){
            const ChildComponent = React.lazy(() => 
                import(
                    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
                    /* webpackChunkName: "childb" */ './ChildB.jsx'
                )
            );
            
            return (
                <Suspense fallback="">
                    <ChildComponent myprop={ this.state.somevalue } />
                </Suspense>
            )
        }
    
        __renderChildComponent(){
            switch(this.state.myoption){
                case "1":
                    return this.__renderChildComponent1();
                    break;
    
                case "2":
                    return this.__renderChildComponent2();
                    break;
    
                default:
                    return null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        render(){
            <div className="component-a">
                { this.__renderChildComponent() }
            </div>
        }
    }
```

I've tried to instead assign my Child Component against a property of my ParentComponent e.g.:

```
    this.ChildComponent = false;
    if(!this.childComponent){
        const ChildComponent = React.lazy(() => 
            import(
                /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
                /* webpackChunkName: "childb" */ './ChildB.jsx'
            )
        );
            
        this.childComponent = (
            <Suspense fallback="">
                <ChildComponent myprop={ this.state.somevalue } />
            </Suspense>
        )
    } else {
        return this.childComponent;
    }
```

But upon doing this my childComponent no longer recieves state updates from its parent.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure if this a good pattern**, but the solution that came to my mind is having an array in state for children components:

```
this.state.children=[null,null] // initially they are two indexes of null, for the two children.
```

every time `this.state.myoption` is updated, check if the corresponding child is `null`, and if it is, lazy load.

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.children[this.state.myoption] === null) {
    import("PATH").then((component) => {
      const newChildrenArray = [...this.state.children];
      newChildrenArray[this.state.myoption] = component;
      this.setState({ children: newChildrenArray });
    });
  }
}
```

finally, inside render, check if the needed component is available, and render it.

```
 render(){
let Component = this.state.children[this.state.myoption] 
<div className="component-a">
   {Component?<Component/>:""} 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go, but I think this may have the same issue as my second code snippet above, the Child Component wouldn't receive the updated value from the parent component "this.state.somevalue" 

Currently I've resorted to checking "somevalue" in the comnponentDidUpdate function, seeing if it's changed and if it has re-rendering the Child Component - it works but feels very hacky :(